# How to remove starting bullet of an unordered list

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to design gallery of images using php and css. I have placed the images in unordered list like,

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<?
while($data=mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
 $pic=$data[2];
  if ($pic)
  {
 $path="http://www.myworkdemo.com/pecifica/photos/".$pic;
 }
 ?>
 <li style="list-style-type:none; float: left; margin-left:4px; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
<img src=<?=$path?> width=300 height=240></img>
  <!--<td class='delete'><a href='addproject.php?ProjId=<?=$data[0]?>&action=edit' >Edit</a></td>-->
 <div class='delete'><a href='images.php?picid=<?=$data[0]?>&action=delete' class="ask">Delete</a></div>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

And i got all the images but one bullet(starting) was not removed from the list. my gallery after css formatting is like

[image]
and due to that bullet i lost the alignment of first row images. please guide me.

Comment: If you provide a link to this screenshot, I'd be happy to have a look at what might be causing it.

Comment: Can you show the rendered HTML (*not* the server-side script that *generates* the HTML), as CSS is client-side. And, ideally, post a live demo that reproduces your problem at somewhere like [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/).

Comment: You can also check by `right-click` and `inspect` what is causing it.  Using plugins like firebug or chrome's built in code inspector.  It will show if your inline tag is being overridden.

Comment: FYI, I went to the url in your image, and didn't get stopped by any security, so am assuming you have it disable while you work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It lies in two of your CSS files.

Line 514  http://www.myworkdemo.com/pecifica/admin/css/style1.css

```
.block .block_content ul li {
    background: url("../images/li.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 7px transparent;
```

Line 523,  http://www.myworkdemo.com/pecifica/admin/css/style.css

```
.block .block_content ul li {
    background: url("../images/li.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 7px transparent;
```

Disabling both of these with firebug eliminated the bullet (which is actually a custom gif file).  You'll need to review how you're using the involved classes.

Answer (score 3):

Very easily:

```
list-style-type: none;
```

Also consider `list-style: none;` if the bullet is actually an image not rendered by the browser.

Comment: Am I missing something or does the OP not have exactly this? Also, this doesn't explain why only the first item has a bullet.